# How to know if an array contains empty string but exclude 0

Tags: php

How do I count non-empty array items in PHP but excluding 0. Zero is a falsy value that's why it's not included in the counting when I use array_filter. In the example below what I want to get when I echo the count is 4 since there are 4 items in the array

```
$numbers = array(0,2,4,2);
echo count(array_filter($numbers));
```

And if it is like this the output should be 5, empty string excluded from the counting but the 2 zeroes are still included:

```
$numbers = array(0,2,4,2,'',0);
echo count(array_filter($numbers));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unwanted elements from `$numbers` with [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff).

```
echo count(array_diff($numbers, array(0)));  // 3
```